# Calculations in python

Tags: python

I'm finding it difficult to calculate a part of my program in Python.

```
import random
CharacterOne= input("Enter the First players name:")
CharacterTwo= input("Enter the Second players name:")
ch1str=int(input(CharacterOne+" has a strength of:"))
ch1skl=int(input(CharacterOne+" has a skill of:"))
ch2str=int(input(CharacterTwo+" has a strength of:"))
ch2skl=int(input(CharacterTwo+" has a skill of:"))
strdif=int(ch1str-ch2str)
if strdif<0:
   strdif=ch2str-ch1str
strmod=strdif//5
skldif=int(ch1skl-ch2skl)
if skldif<0:
   skldif=ch2skl-ch1skl
sklmod=skldif//5

num1=random.randrange(1,6)
num2=random.randrange(1,6)
if num1>num2:
   ch1str+=strmod
   ch1skl+=sklmod
   ch2str-=strmod
   ch2skl-=sklmod
   play1 = True
if num2>num1:
   ch2str+=strmod
   ch2skl+=sklmod
   ch1str-=strmod
   ch1skl-=sklmod
   play1 = False
if ch1skl<0:
   ch1skl=0
if ch2skl<0:
   ch2skl=0
if ch1str=0:
   print(CharacterOne+" is now dead")
if ch2str=0:
   print(CharacterTwo+" is now dead")
if play1==True:
   print(CharacterOne+" won this round, now has",ch1str,"strength and",ch1skl,"skill")
   print(CharacterTwo+" lost this round, now has",ch2str,"strength and",ch2skl,"skill")
if play1==False:
   print(CharacterTwo+" won this round, now has",ch2str,"strength and",ch2skl,"skill")
   print(CharacterOne+" lost this round, now has",ch1str,"strength and",ch1skl,"skill")
```

This is the code, for some reason when I enter the strength and skill for both characters the program prints what I entered and doesnt actually calculate the new strength and skill using the str and skl mod and dif.

Comment: Are you sure that `strmod` and `sklmod` are greater than 0? `ch1str += strmod` won't do anything if `strmod` is zero.

Comment: furthermore, you have a condition where you are taking two random numbers, and comparing them. You havent taken into account the case where the two random numbers are the same. No modifications get made in that case. You've also set up a scenario where "CharacterOne is now dead" or "CharacterTwo is now dead" will never be displayed. You are setting ch1str and ch2str to zero directly before checking if they're below zero. Why are you doing this?

Comment: So how would I make it choose two new numbers if they do turn out the same? Would I make another if statement?

Comment: You don't have to choose two numbers. Choose one, and check if it is below or above a threshold. num1 = rand.randrange(1,6) and then if num >= 2

Comment: Also please use `else` and `elif` for what they were invented. ;)

Comment: Also, are you sure you're putting in numbers high enough such that strmod // 5 is not resulting in 0?

Comment: so num>=2 would check if its above or below a threshold? oh and how would i make it so only a number in a certain range can be entered near the top of the code?

Comment: That's a pretty trivial problem. Have you learnt about while loops yet? They can be used to solve that problem.

Comment: Nope i haven't learnt about while loops yet, i'm in secondary school so I don't really know a lot about coding

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole lot of stuff going on here, and i'm not sure you understand what your logic is actually doing. In this case, no matter the strength or skill of either player, the winner of the round is determined by a random number. Also, please look into else and elif statements for conditionals.

```
import random
import math
CharacterOne= input("Enter the First players name:")
CharacterTwo= input("Enter the Second players name:")
ch1str=int(input(CharacterOne+" has a strength of:"))
ch1skl=int(input(CharacterOne+" has a skill of:"))
ch2str=int(input(CharacterTwo+" has a strength of:"))
ch2skl=int(input(CharacterTwo+" has a skill of:"))

#you dont need to cast to int here, your vars are already ints. Also, you can use the absolute value to avoid the extra conditional.
strdif = abs(ch1str-ch2str)
strmod = strdif//5

skldif = abs(ch1skl-ch2skl)
sklmod = skldif//5

num1=random.randrange(1,6)

if num1>=3:
   ch1str+=strmod
   ch1skl+=sklmod
   ch2str-=strmod
   ch2skl-=sklmod
   play1 = True
else:
   ch2str+=strmod
   ch2skl+=sklmod
   ch1str-=strmod
   ch1skl-=sklmod
   play1 = False
#no idea what you're doing here. Do we care if their stats are in the negative? Why not just compare to <0?
#if ch1skl<0:
#   ch1skl=0
#if ch2skl<0:
#   ch2skl=0
#if ch1str<0:
#   ch1str=0
#if ch2str<0:
#   ch2str=0

if ch1str<0:
   print(CharacterOne+" is now dead")
if ch2str<0:
   print(CharacterTwo+" is now dead")

#Do you want the winner to be determined randomly? Currently your stats have no effect on the winner
if play1==True:
   print(CharacterOne+" won this round, now has",ch1str,"strength and",ch1skl,"skill")
   print(CharacterTwo+" lost this round, now has",ch2str,"strength and",ch2skl,"skill")
else:
   print(CharacterTwo+" won this round, now has",ch2str,"strength and",ch2skl,"skill")
   print(CharacterOne+" lost this round, now has",ch1str,"strength and",ch1skl,"skill")
```

Comment: Enter the First players name:Tom
    Enter the Second players name:Victor
    Tom has a strength of:21
    Tom has a skill of:18
    Victor has a strength of:17
    Victor has a skill of:15
    Tom won this round, now has 21 strength and 18 skill
    Victor lost this round, now has 17 strength and 15 skill

Comment: Do you see why? (21 - 18) // 5 is equal to 0. That's why nothing is changing. Your strmod and skillmod are both equal to 0.

Comment: So how would i fix this problem? sorry if im being demanding im new to coding as i'm only in secondary school, i havent actually went into depth with coding. So i'm trying to learn as much as i can through sites like these.

Comment: Either change your 5 down to a smaller number, or use larger differences in numbers. For example, player1 can have str 100, and player 2 can have str 50. That will cause a strmod of 10. Try those out.

Comment: when player one and player 2 enter there attribute values how would i make it so they can only choose in a range? And also thanks it worked ^-^

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/ do the python course. You don't know python syntax really yet, so this should be good for you.